# How to cache custom pages using W3 Total Cache?

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache

Some posts are requested through Ajax.

```
<?php
// Filename: ajax-posts.php
require_once "wp-load.php";
echo my_get_post($_GET["id"]);
?>
```

How can I make theese Ajax requests cacheable by W3 Total Cache?

Comment: For something like this, would it be more effective to use the [Wordpress Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) and cache the requests that way? Also, is there a specific reason you're not routing the ajax requests through admin-ajax.php and using a [wp_ajax_](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) action instead of including wp-load.php? I'm not sure what your set-up or intent is with this and I don't wnat to steer you wrong, so maybe someone else can chime in, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. Getting W3 Total Cache to talk to a non-WP call in manor listed above isn't (easily) possible. I completely agree with @allenericr comments. The Transients API is very straight forward and quite simple to implement. In addition, @allenericr, comment on using admin-ajax.php is also spot on. It's not sure it's best practices to just include wp-load and call it good (sounds like a big security hole).